# Delphi Editor Color scheme

Tags: delphi, ide, colors

I was wondering if someone could post a Delphi IDE editor color scheme, rather than the ones that come with Delphi. I am getting tired of this white/black color and i am searching for good examples on the internet, but i have found nothing so far. Does anyone can post a .reg (delphi stores the ide color in Registry) and a screenshot of delphi IDE so a can copy it?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60550277/how-to-keep-my-custom-ide-color-scheme-after-switching-themes/60553935#60553935

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the Delphi IDE Theme Editor.

- Blog of the [`Delphi IDE Theme Editor`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/is-your-delphi-ide-hot-or-not-introducing-the-delphi-ide-theme-editor/).
- [Code google site](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-ide-theme-editor/)

[image]

Comment: the best one i have found so far.

Comment: The new version is very cool. Just a question. Can I Theme the all IDE ? and not only the editor ? Thanks

Comment: @Jlouro, Yes you can apply a theme to the IDE, try the [Delphi IDE Colorizer plugin](https://code.google.com/p/delphi-ide-theme-editor/)

Comment: I actually downloaded and built this from source and it works, once I copy the necessary folders to correct locations. But what about changing the colors of the IDE itself?

Answer (score 15):

Check this entry blog [`Editor Theme for Delphi IDE`](http://www.armin-pfaeffle.de/blog/2010/11/editor-theme-for-delphi-ide-version-7-xe/). here you can find a [collection of reg. files](http://www.armin-pfaeffle.de/files/delphi/delphi-editor-themes-v1.2.rar) to apply this theme (Dark Theme) to the Delphi IDE. also you can modify the reg file to create your own theme.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this still leaves the rest of Delphi with black text on a white background. Delphi does seem to be very keen to honour the system colour settings.

Comment: The black theme is cool, but it could have more theme options (there are only 2 themes). Is there any other site I can find custom themes?

Comment: @Rafael, i don't know about the existence of another site, but you can modify the reg files posted in the site to create a new theme for your Delphi IDE.

Comment: wow, another guy from i think Germany still developing this to xe8. Thanks
[link](https://github.com/RWarnecke/Delphi-Editor-Theme/tree/master/dark)

Answer (score 13):

White/black? You mean you don't use TP colors? (tools->editor options->Classic) Modernist heresy![image: Classic editor look]

Comment: Lol. I guess i missed this one!

Comment: Ah, well it funny what you can do with the high res screens of nowadays: http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/idescreenshot.png (FPC's TP like IDE).  I use this for FPC work, and even at work for a lot of little programming.

Comment: @Marco van de Voort: we were using high screen res back with TP7 or so in 1990. There was a hack to get the DOS IDE running in something like 128x50 text mode and it made the whole thing so much more usable.

Comment: I know, I did also. (Trident card did 132x60 even iirc). This is only taken at 1280x1024. Must have a 2048x1536 screenshot somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I just love my color scheme and have shared this colors years ago in a Delphi newsgroup. It is important turn on the ClearType font smoothing and use a font like BitStream Vera Sans Mono, it is a perfect font for a dark background.

[image: my Delphi 7 ide]

**EDIT**:

- Reg file is here: http://www.mediafire.com/?g3ufaua1b07lbw5
- Larger pictore of ide: http://www.mediafire.com/?vf1vs5ja6myf37m

Comment: where can I put the reg file? there are a place here in stackoverflow?

Comment: you'll need to find free file hosting (http://www.google.com.au/search?q=free+file+hosting), upload it there and link to it.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added links to reg file and to a larger picture.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a reg scheme, but as no one talked about it yet... 
I use CnPack [CnWizards](http://www.cnpack.org).That add some colors to your code, including making '**begin ... end**'s much more clear by a line that bound them both.

Till the Black/white(or blue) looks better. :)
[image: CnPackExample]

I'm a new user of it, but I think that you will probably love that in combination with RRUZ application. Regards,