# How to keep my (custom) IDE color scheme after switching themes?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

Delphi Rio comes with two color schemes: dark and light.
I open Tools->Options->Editor->Color and changed the dark color scheme to make it even darker.
[image]

But after switching to the 'light' theme and then back to the 'dark' theme my colors were lost:

[image]

I don't get how this color editor works. How do I permanently store my colors?

Comment: Please stop adding bogus tags. If you are asking about Rio, that's the only version tag that should be here. I already fixed your tags once.

Comment: Ok, In `Rio` there are new menu items in the previous "Layout" menu, which I can not test myself, so I deleted my answer.

Comment: Otoh, it would be logical that the `Custom` item (which is empty in your case) would give you your own setup, even if `Dark` and `Light` only gives the presets?

Comment: @TomBrunberg - Yes it would make sense indeed but it won't let me change the "Custom" item.

Comment: It doesn't matter which menu I use to change the theme (I could also do it from "Options"). The bug still manifests.

Comment: This is a bug. https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19524

Comment: Man.... how can Embarcadero release a product with such an obvious bug. It is like they never ever tried to edit a single color.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar - can you post this as an answer? I will accept it.

Comment: Feel free to self answer.

Comment: If you don't have to switch themes often, you can set your theme, then go to registry Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight (not 100% sure it is right key) and export that. When you switch themes, you can restore you settings after you close the IDE. It is not proper solution, but maybe it will be enough for your needs. You can also add that to the answer to make it more substantial.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar - I was working exactly on a similar "patch" :) I would call it rather a "backup solution" in the case when I accidentally switch the theme and blow up my color settings.

Comment: Dark themes were introduced in 10.2.2 Tokyo and this is when I reported the bug... it was there from the start. https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/new-in-10-2-2-dark-ide-theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Know Delphi bug (no wonder why Delphi will [fall out of Tiobe index](https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/)) as reported by Dalija: [quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19524](http://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19524).

**Workaround:**
Setup editor colors for "dark" theme and save the key.
Setup editor colors for "light" them and save the registry.
When you want to switch between themes, shutdown Delphi and load the registry key.

**Update:**
There is a similar bug while trying to customize the Object Inspector. Color settings are lots without even changing the theme!

**Dark theme example:**
Here are color for pure-dark (green font, black bkg) theme:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight]
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Additional
>   search match highlight] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False"
>   "Underline"="False" "Default Foreground"="False" "Default
>   Background"="False" "Foreground Color New"="$006202E3" "Background
>   Color New"="$0033001B"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Assembler]
>   "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="$00FF53BE" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Attribute Names] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clWhite" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Attribute Values] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clRed" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Brace
>   Highlight] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False"
>   "Default Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground
>   Color New"="$00804917" "Background Color New"="$00791116"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Character]
>   "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clYellow" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Code
>   folding tree] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False"
>   "Default Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground
>   Color New"="$00597D73" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Comment]
>   "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clSilver" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Diff
>   addition] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clNavy" "Background Color New"="clYellow"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Diff
>   deletion] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clNavy" "Background Color New"="clRed"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Diff
>   move] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clNavy" "Background Color New"="clBlue"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Disabled
>   break] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="True" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clBlack" "Background Color New"="$001B1514"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Enabled
>   break] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="True" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clBlack" "Background Color New"="$00000F0F"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Error
>   line] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="True" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clBlack" "Background Color New"="$0036234B"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Execution point] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="True" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clBlack" "Background Color New"="$0033001A"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Float]
>   "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="$00AEFFFF" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Folded
>   code] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="$0000FF80" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Hex]
>   "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clFuchsia" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Hot
>   Link] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="True" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clAqua" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Identifier]
>   "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clLime" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Illegal
>   Char] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clRed" "Background Color New"="clWhite"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Invalid
>   break] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="True" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clBlack" "Background Color New"="$002B2B33"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Line
>   Highlight] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False"
>   "Default Foreground"="True" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground
>   Color New"="clBlack" "Background Color New"="$00350000"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Line
>   Number] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="$00757464" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Marked
>   block] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="$00F9FFD2" "Background Color New"="$00CA5735"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Modified
>   line] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="$0000FF80" "Background Color New"="clYellow"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Number]
>   "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clYellow" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Octal]
>   "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clFuchsia" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Plain
>   text] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="$00C9FF80" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Preprocessor]
>   "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="$003C92DF" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Reserved
>   word] "Bold"="True" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="$008CFF4F" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Right
>   margin] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clSilver" "Background Color New"="clWhite"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Scripts]
>   "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clRed" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Search
>   match] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clBlue" "Background Color New"="clYellow"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\String]
>   "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clRed" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Structural
>   Highlighting] "Enabled"="True" "Color1"="$00FF86FF"
>   "Color2"="$00FE85CD" "Color3"="$00F1A7B0" "Color4"="$00E1CA7B"
>   "FlowControlEnabled"="True" "FlowControlLocation"="1"
>   "ShowSingleLine"="True"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Symbol]
>   "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clLime" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Sync
>   edit background] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False"
>   "Default Foreground"="True" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground
>   Color New"="clBlack" "Background Color New"="clGray"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Sync
>   edit highlight] "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False"
>   "Default Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground
>   Color New"="clBlue" "Background Color New"="clWhite"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Tags]
>   "Bold"="True" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clAqua" "Background Color New"="clBlack"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Editor\Highlight\Whitespace]
>   "Bold"="False" "Italic"="False" "Underline"="False" "Default
>   Foreground"="False" "Default Background"="False" "Foreground Color
>   New"="clLime" "Background Color New"="clBlack"

[March Headline: Delphi is about to fall out of the TIOBE index top 20](https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/)